# Adding a Title and text fields to Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint

I have a small program already started with multiple menu items.

When an item is clicked, I would like for something to show on the frame, and when another item is clicked, the first disappears and the second appears.

I can print to console, but cannot seem to print to frame.

Any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class melco extends JFrame{


public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Salesman Resources");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(exit);

    JMenu orders = new JMenu("Orders");
    menubar.add(orders);
    JMenuItem bookedorders = new JMenuItem("Booked Orders");
    orders.add(bookedorders);
    JMenuItem backorders = new JMenuItem("BackOrders");
    orders.add(backorders);

    JMenu customers = new JMenu("Customers");
    menubar.add(customers);
    JMenuItem customersales = new JMenuItem("Customer Sales");
    customers.add(customersales);
    JMenuItem customeritems = new JMenuItem("Customer Items");
    customers.add(customeritems);
    JMenuItem customerprices = new JMenuItem("Customer Prices");
    customers.add(customerprices);
    JMenuItem customerlistings = new JMenuItem("Customer Listings");
    customers.add(customerlistings);

    JMenu inv = new JMenu("INV");
    menubar.add(inv);
    JMenuItem surplusinv = new JMenuItem("Surplus Inv");
    inv.add(surplusinv);
    JMenuItem stockinv = new JMenuItem("Stock Inv");
    inv.add(stockinv);

    JMenu search = new JMenu("Searh");
    menubar.add(search);
    JMenuItem itemsearch = new JMenuItem("Item Search");
    search.add(itemsearch);
    JMenuItem customersearch = new JMenuItem("Customer Search");
    search.add(customersearch);

    JMenu menulostsales = new JMenu("Lost Sales");
    menubar.add(menulostsales);
    JMenuItem lostsales = new JMenuItem("Lost Sales");
    menulostsales.add(lostsales);


    JMenu menumarginadvisor = new JMenu("Margin Advisor");
    menubar.add(menumarginadvisor);
    JMenuItem marginadvisor = new JMenuItem("Margin Advisor");
    menumarginadvisor.add(marginadvisor);


    JMenu menumakeandhold = new JMenu("Make and Hold");
    menubar.add(menumakeandhold);
    JMenuItem makeandhold = new JMenuItem("Make and Hold");

    menumakeandhold.add(makeandhold);

    makeandhold.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Make and Hold is pressed");
                System.out.println("Hello World");                  
// This is Make and Hold Area

            }
        }
    );          

    class exitaction implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }
        exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());


}

}
```

Comment: welcome to this forum :-) To make it easy for potential helpers, please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print to frame because a frame doesn't have a print method. If you want to add the text to the frame directly you should draw it. That requires to override `paint` method by the technique below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class melco extends JFrame{

  String str;
  int x = 100, y = 100;

  public melco(String title){
    super(title);
  }

  void print(String s){
    str = s;
    repaint();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    if (str != null)
      g.drawString(str, x, y);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    final melco frame = new melco("Salesman Resources");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(exit);

    JMenu orders = new JMenu("Orders");
    menubar.add(orders);
    JMenuItem bookedorders = new JMenuItem("Booked Orders");
    orders.add(bookedorders);
    JMenuItem backorders = new JMenuItem("BackOrders");
    orders.add(backorders);

    JMenu customers = new JMenu("Customers");
    menubar.add(customers);
    JMenuItem customersales = new JMenuItem("Customer Sales");
    customers.add(customersales);
    JMenuItem customeritems = new JMenuItem("Customer Items");
    customers.add(customeritems);
    JMenuItem customerprices = new JMenuItem("Customer Prices");
    customers.add(customerprices);
    JMenuItem customerlistings = new JMenuItem("Customer Listings");
    customers.add(customerlistings);

    JMenu inv = new JMenu("INV");
    menubar.add(inv);
    JMenuItem surplusinv = new JMenuItem("Surplus Inv");
    inv.add(surplusinv);
    JMenuItem stockinv = new JMenuItem("Stock Inv");
    inv.add(stockinv);

    JMenu search = new JMenu("Searh");
    menubar.add(search);
    JMenuItem itemsearch = new JMenuItem("Item Search");
    search.add(itemsearch);
    JMenuItem customersearch = new JMenuItem("Customer Search");
    search.add(customersearch);

    JMenu menulostsales = new JMenu("Lost Sales");
    menubar.add(menulostsales);
    JMenuItem lostsales = new JMenuItem("Lost Sales");
    menulostsales.add(lostsales);


    JMenu menumarginadvisor = new JMenu("Margin Advisor");
    menubar.add(menumarginadvisor);
    JMenuItem marginadvisor = new JMenuItem("Margin Advisor");
    menumarginadvisor.add(marginadvisor);


    JMenu menumakeandhold = new JMenu("Make and Hold");
    menubar.add(menumakeandhold);
    JMenuItem makeandhold = new JMenuItem("Make and Hold");

    menumakeandhold.add(makeandhold);

    makeandhold.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
          System.out.println("Make and Hold is pressed");
          frame.print("Make and Hold is pressed");
          System.out.println("Hello World");
          frame.print("Hello World");
// This is Make and Hold Area

        }
      }
    );

    class exitaction implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
    exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());


  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to progress forward!
Next, I will attempt to add some text boxes and Buttons to a different event handler.

Answer (score 1):

> I can print to console, but cannot seem to print to frame.

What do you mean exactly?

If you want to set a title on the Frame you can use setTitle:

```
frame.setTitle("a title");
```

Otherwise, if you want to add some text you have at least to add some component to your JFrame.
Have a look at [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
frame.getContentPane().add(label);
```

when you need to change the text:

```
label.setText("some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

- Don't ever use the EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread) for other things apart from letting it handle the GUI. `main()` **method in Java Gui exits after scheduling the construction of GUI to the Event Dispatcher Thread. So its the EDT which handles it.**

**Eg:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

         public void run(){

             myframe.setVisible(true);

           } 
      }
  }
```

- You need something like `JLable` for adding things like **Title**.
- You can add a `JPanel` to the `JFrame` and then add a `JTextField` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't print to a frame.  Maybe you want to add a JTextArea and append data to it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you need something to display on the frame, something like a `JLabel`??

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel(); // You'll probably need to declare this as final
frame.add(lblMessage);
```

Then in your action listener could do something like

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    label.setText("This is a message from the menu item");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you add a MouseListener on the JMenuItems? You can hold the most recent "message" reference as a member variable and remove it from the JFrame when another MouseListener is fired.